# Oracle XMLTable / XMLTYPE (no idea)

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xmltype, xmltable

im trying to create DataBase using OracleXE11 and what im tring to do is create XML tables and input data into them.

Step 1:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
  customerId int Primary KEY,
  signUpDate Date NOT NULL,
  CustomerData XMLTYPE,
  CustomerAdress XMLTYPE);
```

Step 2:

CustomerData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CustomerData>
    <Customer>
        <name>Alex Smith</name>
        <type>Fleet</type>
        <nip>1234567890</nip>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <name>Saly North</name>
        <type>person</type>
        <nip>2345678901</nip>
    </Customer>
<CustomerData>
```

CustomerAdress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CustomerAdress>
    <Adress>
        <city>Xxxx</city>
        <street>Yyyy 2</Street>
        <postcode>56-200</postcode>
    </Adress>
    <Adress>
        <city>Zzzz</city>
        <Street>Uuuu 5</street>
        <postcode>57-300</postcode>
    </Adress>
<CustomerAdress>
```

Step 3:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY XMLDIR AS 'C:\xml_files';
```

Step 4:
Now i have a problem because i don't know how to input those data. 
I've tried to:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (customerId, signUpDate, CustomerData, CustomerAdress) VALUES 
(1, to_date('12-05-1970','dd-mm-yyyy'), XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'CustomerData.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')), XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'CustomerAdress.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
```

but it returns me 1 row (i know why... because in creating only 1 row using all xml files i've declared)

I wondered... maybe a PROCEDURE (PL/SQL) will help me with it

And another problems are (i need to use them all for update/insert/delete): 
 - Xpath
 - DOM
 - SAX
 - Xquery
 - creating XML Schema to validate inputed XML File
 - write XML file from DB to file.xml on Desktop
 - read XML file.xml from Desktop to DB

Im not even sure if im started well with it.
//------------------------------------------------------------//
Im trying to insert xmlfile into table but i dont know how to separate data form xmlfile

what im expecting

ROW 1:

```
customerId = 1 || 
signUpDate = 12-05-1970 || 
CustomerData = <name>Alex Smith</name> <type>Fleet</type> <nip>1234567890</nip> ||
CustomerAdress = <city>Xxxx</city> <street>Yyyy 2</Street> <postcode>56-200</postcode>
```

ROW 2:

```
customerId = 2 || 
signUpDate = 26-10-2007 || 
CustomerData = <name>Saly North</name> <type>Person</type> <nip>2345678901</nip> ||
CustomerAdress = <city>Zzzz</city> <street>Uuuu 5</Street> <postcode>57-300</postcode>
```

.
.
.

ROW n:

```
customerId = n || 
signUpDate = dd-mm-yyy || 
CustomerData = <name>Xxx Yyy</name> <type>Xxx</type> <nip>nnnnnnnnnn</nip> ||
CustomerAdress = <city>Xxx</city> <street>Xxx</Street> <postcode>xx-xxx</postcode>
```

in my opinion thats how XMLTYPE table should looks like but i may be wrong (also i need to operate on this XMLDB using simply operations like insert/delete/update using sql query)

Comment: If you insert one row into a table, you get one row back on a select.  What exactly are you expecting?  Please explain what you are trying to select out.  Your other question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for XMLTable function, it is very useful, if you need to parse xml files.
You can load xml into another table, for example customer_xml and then use XMLTable function to parse xml data and insert into main table customer. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (customerid NUMBER,
                       signupdate DATE,
                       name VARCHAR2(255),
                       type VARCHAR2(255),
                       nip  VARCHAR2(255))
/
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_XML (dataxml XMLTYPE)
/
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_customer_id START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
/
CREATE PROCEDURE p_customer_insert
IS
TYPE t_customer_aat IS TABLE OF customer%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
l_customer_aat t_customer_aat;
l_dataxml XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT dataxml INTO l_dataxml
    FROM customer_xml;

    SELECT seq_customer_id.NEXTVAL, sysdate, x.* 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_customer_aat
    FROM XMLTABLE('/CustomerData/Customer' PASSING l_dataxml
                                           COLUMNS
                                           name VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'name',
                                           type VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'type',
                                           nip  VARCHAR2(255) PATH 'nip') x;

     FORALL indx in 1..l_customer_aat.COUNT
         INSERT INTO customer VALUES l_customer_aat(indx);
     COMMIT;
END;
```